# How to store data from database in multidimensional array

Tags: c++

I am using Oracle as my database,and C++ as the language to fetch the data from the database. Let say I want to fetch data from table Customer,how should I store it? In Java, I use Vector < MyClassDefinition>. However the way to define a vector in C++ is quite complex for me. The data I fetch from the database have more than 6 column, and if I want to store it in vector, the declaration of 6 column is quite too long.


1. Is there any other way to store the data from a table in a temporary collection is C++? 

2. Or I should use vector,but I am doing it wrong?

3. Or should I just use a pointer and split it into column and row by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a std::vector of a class reprenting a row.

```
class Row
{
  int a;
  string b;
  int c;
  float f;
  double g;
  string d;
};

std::vector<Row> rows;
```

If some columns might be nullable, then [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)